# what size_t ,flags,host_ptr with a example in detail description as how to take size and what size should be considered?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

```
cl_mem clCreateBuffer ( cl_context context,
cl_mem_flags flags,
size_t size,
void *host_ptr,
cl_int *errcode_ret)
```

here what *host ptr refers to ?

Comment: can anyone explain me as im working on opencl and new to it?

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html)?

Comment: yes i have gone through but not clear about the arguments